# Open View from TableView

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'm quite new at using Monotouch. I have a problem finding tutorials on how to open a new view from within `public override void RowSelected`. Can I just call:

```
SecondView second = new SecondView(string sometext)
```

Or is it done differently?

Comment: in objC - you can either us UINavigationController pushViewController (your view would be in a UIViewController) or presentModalViewController.  I imagine there's a parallel in monotouch - their classes mirror pretty close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to show the view modally or not.

Somewhere you will need a reference to your viewcontroller (we'll assume it is m_Controller for now). Once you have that, for a modal view, you can call:

```
m_Controller.PresentModalViewController(new SecondView(someText), true);
```

and for non-modal:

```
m_Controller.PushViewController(new SecondView(someText), true);
```